# Как получить количество отображаемых символов в UILabel?

Tags: ios, swift

Есть `UILabel`, в котором отображается очень длинный текст. Однако количество строк в нём всегда должно быть равно 5 и соответсвенно текст выводится не весь, а лишь его начало. Необходимо узнать, сколько символов или какая подстрока реально видна на экране устройства.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно прикинуть сколько текста влезет в фрейм `UILabel`:

```
func numberOfCharactersThatFitLabel() -> Int {
    let font = yourLabel.font
    let fontRef = CTFontCreateWithName(font?.fontName as CFString?, font!.pointSize, nil)
    let attributedString  = NSAttributedString.init(string: yourLabel.text!, attributes: [String(kCTFontAttributeName): fontRef])
    let frameSetterRef = CTFramesetterCreateWithAttributedString(attributedString)
    var characterFitRange = CFRange()
    CTFramesetterSuggestFrameSizeWithConstraints(frameSetterRef, CFRangeMake(0,0), nil, CGSize(width: yourLabel.bounds.width, height: linesCount * font!.lineHeight), &characterFitRange);
    return characterFitRange.length;
}
```

Получить результат:

```
// Количество символов
print(numberOfCharactersThatFitLabel())
// Подстрока
print(yourLabel.text!.substring(to: yourLabel.text!.index(yourLabel.text!.startIndex, offsetBy: numberOfCharactersThatFitLabel())))
```

Comment: А linesCount это что? Это то, что у меня по условию равно 5?